# TypeScript doesn't match conditional types properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a following component (simplified version):

```
type ValueHelper<Clearable extends boolean> = Clearable extends true
    ? string | null
    : string;

type Props<Clearable extends boolean> = {
    clearable?: Clearable;
    onChange: (value: ValueHelper<Clearable>) => void;
    value: ValueHelper<Clearable>;
};

const Input = <Clearable extends boolean = false>({ clearable, value, onChange }: Props<Clearable>) => {
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        if (clearable && inputValue === '') {
            onChange(null);
            return;
        }
        onChange(inputValue);
    }

    return (
        <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    );
}
```

For some reason TypeScript complains about `null` argument in `onChange` function, which seems to be wrong, since my conditional type `ValueHelper` checks if `clearable` is `true`, and if so, `null` should be allowed.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Typescript; Typescript does [control-flow type narrowing](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/narrowing/) on variables, but not on *type variables* like your `Clearable`. So a test like `if(clearable)` can narrow the type of the variable `clearable` to be something more specific than `Clearable`, but it cannot narrow `Clearable` itself to be something more specific. Therefore as far as Typescript is concerned, it's as if you didn't do the `if` check and `Clearable` could still be `string` instead of `string | null`.

In this case a type assertion is probably the simplest solution: *you* know that `null` is assignable to `ValueHelper<Clearable>` in this branch even if Typescript doesn't know it, so instead of `null` you can write `null as ValueHelper<Clearable>`.